# html/javascript/css how to combine and fix this

Tags: javascript, html, function

ok well this is everything but my problem is very small..
the page is setup, the point system is correct all i need to do is have the inputs show match up to the point system and show the alert associated with it.

the issue is when a user enters commands in the text box's it should alert what there rank is (pro,novice,beginner,noob)

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <script>
     function system(){

     var point=document.world.system.txt_points.value
     var tourn=document.world.system.txt_tourn.value
     var level=document.world.system.txt_level.value
     var check=document.world.system.txt_check.value
     var results=document.world.system.txt_results.value

     if ((point>=100000)&&(level>10)&&(tourn>25))
     {
     results=alert("pro status")
     }
    if((points>=100000)&&(level>10))
    {
   alert("Novice")
    }
   if (point>=100000)
   {
   alert("beginner")
   }

   if (points<100000)
   {
   alert("noob")
   }

   if (check=true)
   {
   alert("pro")

   }

   }
   </script>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
   <form name="world">
   <center>
   <table border=3>
   </center>

   <b>
   <th><font size='16'>defined</font></th>
   </b>
   <th><font size='16'>user input</font></th>

   </center>
   <tr>
   <td>How many points have you earned?</td>
   <td>
   <input type="textbox" name="txt_points" size='50'id='point'>
   </td>
   </tr>


   <tr>
   <td>How many tournaments have you played in?</td>
   <td>
   <input type="text box" size='50'id='tourn' name='txt_tourn'>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>highest level</td>
   <td>
   <input type="text box" size='50'id='level' name ='txt_level'>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Have you won atleast 1 tournement</td>
   <td

    ><center>
       <input type="checkbox"id='check' name=txt_check>
       </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>your world of wizards ranking is </td>
    <td><center>
    <input type="submit"value ="submit">
    <br>
    <input type ="text box" name ="txt_results">
    </center>


    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your `system` function is never called apparently.

Comment: Also all `.world.system`s should be just `.world` I believe, and you will probably need some `else if` instead of just `if`.

Comment: its printing the results i have problems with

Comment: Also there is no such thing as type="text box". It's type="text". And your center tags are opened and closed in invalid places. Center is also a deprecated/obsolete tag.

Comment: At some point, maybe when you submit the form, you need to call the system() function. Otherwise the code inside the system() function will never run.

Comment: so how would i write that out?? i know its in the <input type='submit' value='submit'> area but what would i add in here?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is riddled with invalid markup. I've cleaned it up a little bit (it still has issues), and added an onsubmit to the form to call your system function. I modified your system function a bit too. You weren't referring to your variables with the right names all the time. (points instead of point, etc.). Next time, do some typo checking *before* you post a question or code. Generally one or two typos is accepted as just being overlooked, but yours had a lot. Just a few minutes of looking it over on your part would have gotten you tons closer to begin with.

**HTML**

```
   <form name="world" method="post" onsubmit="system(); return false;">

   <table border=3>



   <th><font size='16'>defined</font></th>

   <th><font size='16'>user input</font></th>


   <tr>
   <td>How many points have you earned?</td>
   <td>
   <input type="text" name="txt_points" size='50' id='point'>
   </td>
   </tr>


   <tr>
   <td>How many tournaments have you played in?</td>
   <td>
   <input type="text" size='50' id='tourn' name='txt_tourn'>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>highest level</td>
   <td>
   <input type="text" size='50' id='level' name ='txt_level'>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td>Have you won atleast 1 tournement</td>
   <td

    >
       <input type="checkbox"id='check' name=txt_check>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>your world of wizards ranking is </td>
    <td>
    <input type="submit"value ="submit">
    <br>
    <input type ="text box" name ="txt_results">



    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function system(){

     var point=document.world.txt_points.value;
     var tourn=document.world.txt_tourn.value;
     var level=document.world.txt_level.value;
     var check=document.world.txt_check.value;
     var results=document.world.txt_results.value

     if ((point>=100000)&&(level>10)&&(tourn>25))
     {
     alert("pro status")
     }
    if((point>=100000)&&(level>10))
    {
   alert("Novice")
    }
   if (point>=100000)
   {
   alert("beginner")
   }

   if (point<100000)
   {
   alert("noob")
   }

   if (check==true)
   {
   alert("pro")

   }

   }
```